# Как добавить текст в TextBox

Tags: visual-basic

Как добавить текст в TextBox при нажатии на клавишу.
Пример:
Я нажал на клавишу 1. В TextBox1 добавилась эта цифра. Еще раз нажал опять добавилась, только уже в TextBox1 две цифры "11"
Теперь перешел я на TextBox2. Опять то же самое только с TextBox2. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо!
Язык **Visual Basic**.

Answer (score 1):

Идея проста: добавить обработчик клика к нужной кнопке, форме и т.д., и по клику в обработчике добавлять значение к свойству Text в TextBox. Например:

```
Private Sub FormX_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _
System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBoxX.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub FormX_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    TextBoxX.Text = TextBoxX.Text + "X"
End Sub
```